# Mean of cumulative distribution function

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

Suppose a CDF given by:

$F(x)=0$ if $x < -2$, $0.6$ if $-2 <= x <= 1$, $1$ if $x > 1$. How can I then calculate $E[X]$ and $E[X^2]$? I found that $E[X]=0$ since there are only jumps, so the PDF must contain points where the slope is infinity, so this means the integral is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are not correct when you say "since there are only jumps, so the PDF must contain points where the slope is infinity". To understand why this is wrong, you may note that the Lebesgue integral of the density $f$ does not depend on the values that $f$ takes at some points $x_1,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}$ (in fact the $x_i$ can even be uncountable). Thus even if $f(-2)=f(1)=+\infty$, you may have $\int tf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t<\infty$.

I will not go into the technical details, but the general formula giving the expectation of $g(X)$ for a nonnegative measurable $g$ is

$$
\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\sum_{k=1}^ng(x_k)\mathbb{P}(X=x_k)+\int g(t)f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t,
$$

where $x_1,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}$ are the discontinuity points of the CDF and $f$ is the density of the "continuous part" with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

In summary, your mistake is forgetting the first term of the formula. I hope this helps you understand the problem with what you said.

As for the problem at hand, take a closer look at your CDF. What is the probability that $X=-2$? What about the probability that $X=1$? (by the way, I think one of your strict inequalities $>$ should be loose one $\ge$)

Once you have answered these questions, the rest of the exercise should be easy.